# Create register form plus send post

Tags: forms, user-registration

I want to make custom register page with some additional fields which will be shown later on users sent posts.

All I need is :

1. Making manual register page

   #### Registration Items That I Need

   - Name
   - Family
   - User Name
   - Email
   - Password
   - Location
   - Radio button to chose type of user account with these elements (Seller - Buyer)
   - Able to send (ph no. - bbm pin - we chat code - website link - price - upload map)
   - Chose account type (Free - Premium )
2. Give access to users to send post and upload photos (but not to be published before admin accept those).

Now what I'm confuse is how to do it! :-) I no have any idea how to start with that. Will be grateful if anyone can help me out with this form.

Thanks.

Comment: This seems a full project, not a question. Please show some code where you are stuck. Then someone may help you.

Comment: @Nilambar I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE:

Call forms into front-end:

```
<?php
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
 get_template_part('header', 'form');
} else {
    get_template_part('header', 'panel');
} ?>
```

`header-form.php` content:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>


  <div role="tabpanel">

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#login" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> Login</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#register" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Register</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#password" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Lost Password?</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="login">
        <h3><?php _e('Have an account?', 'landers'); ?></h3>
        <p><?php _e('Log in or sign up! It&rsquo;s fast &amp; <em>free!</em>', 'landers'); ?></p>

        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php bloginfo('url') ?>/wp-login.php">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="log" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="11" placeholder="<?php _e('Username', 'landers'); ?>" />
                  </div>

                  <div class="form-group">
                   <label class="sr-only" for="user_pass"><?php _e('Password', 'landers'); ?>: </label>
                   <input type="password" class="form-control" name="pwd" value="" size="20" id="user_pass" tabindex="12" placeholder="Password" />
                  </div>


                 <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                      <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                          <input type="checkbox"name="rememberme" value="forever" checked="checked" id="rememberme" tabindex="13" /> Remember me
                        </label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                 <div class="form-group">
                      <?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
                      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Login', 'landers'); ?>" tabindex="14" class="user-submit" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" />
                        <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
                </div>
                </form>
    </div>

    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="register">
        <h3><?php _e('Register for this site!', 'landers'); ?></h3>
            <p><?php _e('Sign up now for the good stuff.', 'landers'); ?></p>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=register', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_login" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_login)); ?>" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="101" placeholder="<?php _e('Username', 'landers'); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="user_email" value="<?php echo esc_attr(stripslashes($user_email)); ?>" size="25" id="user_email" tabindex="102" placeholder="<?php _e('Your Email', 'landers'); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <?php do_action('register_form'); ?>
                    <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Sign up!', 'landers'); ?>" class="user-submit" tabindex="103" />
                    <?php $register = $_GET['register']; if($register == true) { echo '<p><?php _e("Check your email for the password!", "landers"); ?></p>'; } ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?register=true" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>


    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="password">
         <h3><?php _e('Lose something?', 'landers'); ?></h3>
         <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block"><?php _e('Enter your username or email to reset your password.', 'landers'); ?></span>
            <form method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('wp-login.php?action=lostpassword', 'login_post') ?>" class="wp-user-form">
                <div class="username">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="<?php _e('Username or Email', 'landers'); ?>" name="user_login" value="" size="20" id="user_login" tabindex="1001" />
                </div>
                <div class="login_fields">
                    <?php do_action('login_form', 'resetpass'); ?>
                    <input type="submit" name="user-submit" value="<?php _e('Reset my password', 'landers'); ?>" class="btn btn-primary user-submit" tabindex="1002" />
                    <?php $reset = $_GET['reset']; if($reset == true) { echo '<p><?php _e("A message will be sent to your email address.", "landers"); ?></p>'; } ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>?reset=true" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="user-cookie" value="1" />
                </div>
            </form>
    </div>

  </div>

</div>


</div><!-- end alert-->
```

`header-panel.php` content:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade in" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"  data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>


<div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">

            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h3><?php $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); echo '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Welcome, ' . $current_user->user_login . "\n"; ?></h3>
                    <?php global $userdata; get_currentuserinfo(); echo get_avatar($userdata->ID, 60); ?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <p><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></i> You&rsquo;re logged in as <strong><?php echo $current_user->display_name ?></strong></p>
                    <p>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" href="<?php echo wp_logout_url('index.php'); ?>"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></i> Log out</a>
                        <?php if (current_user_can('manage_options')) { 
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm" href="' . admin_url() . '"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-dashboard"></i> ' . __('Admin') . '</a>';
echo '&shy;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" href="' . admin_url() . 'profile.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></i> ' . __('Profile') . '</a>';
    echo '&shy;';
                            echo '<a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="' . admin_url() . 'post-new.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> ' . __('Send Ad') . '</a>';
                            } else { 
                             } ?>

                    </p>
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <?php global $current_user;
                  get_currentuserinfo();
                    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
                    echo '<table class="table table-bordered">';
                    echo '<tbody>';

                    echo '<tr>';             
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Username: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo ''. $current_user->user_login . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';             
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Your email: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo '' . $current_user->user_email . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Your first name: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo ''  . $current_user->user_firstname . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Your last name: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo '' . $current_user->user_lastname . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Your display name: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo '' . $current_user->display_name . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '<tr>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo 'Your ID: ';
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '<td>';
                                  echo '' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
                                  echo '</td>';
                    echo '</tr>';

                    echo '</tbody>';
                    echo '</table>';
                    echo '</div>';
            ?>
        </div>

</div>

</div><!--end of alert-->
```

Till this much i've done. Now I need to add some fields into registration form and give access to publish post (on pending not become live before accept).